# Accessing Draft knowledge article via Apex

Tags: articles

I have a user without "knowledge user" permission and he is able to access draft article via UI however when trying to access from a VF page , in debug logs we are getting error :- System.QueryException: Insufficient access rights: you cannot access draft articles.

Checking "Knowledge user" will imply license usage which we want to avoid, also if salesforce is allowing article accessibility via UI then why not via Apex.

When I check "knowledge user" VF page works fine and does not give any error but why to check that if without checking for that user he can access article from UI.

Not sure what else I can try before expecting a response from someone here. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try the with sharing keyword?  https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm

Comment: I tried with both, with sharing and without sharing, none of them is working.